# How to improve Papervision 3D text rendering quality?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, papervision3d

i'm texturing a plane on papervision 3d and i tried several settings with no avail, text looks bad anyway. Here's an example:
[image: text capture]

this is how i make the material:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        var txt:TextField = new TextField();

        txt.width = 650;
        txt.height = 450;
        txt.multiline = true;
        txt.wordWrap = true;
        txt.selectable = true;
        txt.text = "<center><h1><b>May i have your attention?</b></h1></center>";
        txt.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        mc.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 700, 500,15);
        mc.graphics.endFill();
        mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
        mc.graphics.drawRoundRect(25, 25, 650, 450, 15);
        mc.graphics.endFill();
        txt.x = 25;
        txt.y = 25;
        mc.addChild(txt);
        var mate:MovieMaterial = new MovieMaterial(mc, true, true, true);
        mate.doubleSided = false;
        mate.smooth = false;
        mate.tiled = false;
        mate.interactive = true;
```

this seems to be a problem with resizing. How does texture size works on pv3d?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Andy Zupko's post on Text in Papervision](http://blog.zupko.info/?p=117).
[image: Papervision Text]

And also have a look at [VectorVision](http://barcinskijeanjean.wordpress.com/category/vectorvision/) as it is integrated in Papervision.
[image: Vectorvision Text]

Based on your setup you can pick the solution that works best for you.

Also bare in mind that Papervision hasn't been updated in a long time and might not
be any time soon so it's worth exploring other 3D APIs like [Away3D](http://away3d.com).